# Center dropdown menu on screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

How do i center the dropdown menu on the screen (small screens in particular).

[image]

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown link
  </a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to add `position:absolute, left:0` etc. however without any luck..

Comment: Could you create a code snippet with the essential HTML and CSS included for us to review.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform:

Example:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  left: 50%;
  right: auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

If you need more info, you can read more about it on the [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/)

Answer (score 0):

In this case (in a media query) you can use `position: fixed`, an appropriate `top` value (equal to the height of the navbar), and for the horizontal centering `left: 50%` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: Thanks however Poper still overrides the values. Even though I've added data-display="static"  to pritty much everywhere :)

Comment: I have no idea what "Poper" is or which values that should override, nor what "data-display="static"" should do or have to do with this. Maybe you are using some framework which you didn't mention, but I think you should add more information to your question than you have.